# What's the difference between name() condition and self:: axis

Tags: xpath

For input xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <a>1</a>
    <b>2</b>
    <b>3</b>
    <c>4</c>
</root>
```

I wonder if there is any difference between following xpath

```
//b

//*[name() = 'b']

//*[self::b]     (or //self::b)
```

These expressions seem to be returning the same result but is it everytime true? I have tendency to interchange them freely but have such feeling I shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One difference is that the `name()` function uses the namespace declarations in effect on the passed-in node (usually from the XML source) while the other methods use the namespace declarations from the expression context. This means that the `name()` function can lead to unpredictable results if different input documents use different namespace prefixes.

Another difference is that the `name()` function also works for nodes other than elements. But for elements without namespaces, you can use all methods interchangeably.